# Why is it printing additional random characters?

Tags: c++, arrays, input, output

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLHau.png)

the image shows the input taken and output shown .

I am taking character array as input and printing it, now when i print it, it print input characters as well as some additional random characters, why so??

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;

    char array[100]; 
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        std::cin>>array[i];
    }
    
    std::cout<<array;

    return 0;
}
```

I was expecting it to be printing the letters that i provides as input but it is printing additional character as well as.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger? What do you think `std::cout<<array;` does?

Answer (score 4):

An array of `char` is treated as string and strings are `\0` terminated. Your mixing of `int` and `char` is somewhat odd, but assuming it is what you want, you just need to add the terminator:

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    int n;
    std::cin>>n;

    char array[100]; 
    
    for(int i=0; i<n; i++) 
    {
        std::cin>>array[i];
    }
    array[n] = '\0';
    
    std::cout<<array;

    return 0;
}
```

Though you should use `std::string` for strings. The above code will invoke undefined behavior when the user enters `100` or more for `n`.

Answer (score 3):

The line

```
std::cout<<array;
```

requires that `array` is a valid C-style string, which is an array of characters terminated by a null character. You are violating this rule, by not ensuring that the string is null-terminated.

Your program is printing garbage characters because that line of code will continue printing characters until it happens to find a null character (i.e. a character with the character code `0`).

I suggest that you add the line

```
array[n] = '\0';
```

to add a terminating null character after the loop.